# nodejs require() json from file garbage collection

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection

I'm using a file for storing JSON data. My module makes CRUD actions on the file and I'm using `require()` to load the json, instead of `fs.readFile()`. The issue is, if the file is deleted, using `fs.unlink()`, then calling the file again using `require` still loads the file... which has just been deleted. I'm a bit lost how to get around this, possibly #garbage-collection?

Example:

```
fs.writeFile('foo.json', JSON.stringify({foo:"bar"}), function(){

    var j = require('./foo.json')

    fs.unlink('./foo.json', function(){
        console.log('File deleted')
        var j = require('./foo.json')
        console.log(j)
    })
})
```

Comment: `require` is intended for stable files, and it still shows up because it's in the browser cache.  So your choices are: 1.  Bust the cache, 2. Use `fs.readFile()` instead.  My vote is for the latter.

Comment: going to agree with you here. Think I was looking to reduce callback hell more than anything else. @RobertHarvey do you want to put this up as an answer and I'll check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading a module using `require`, Node.js caches the loaded module internally so that subsequent calls to `require` do not need to access the drive again. The same is true for `.json` files, when loaded using `require`.

That's why your file still is "loaded", although you deleted it.

The solution to this issue is to use the function for loading a file that is appropriate for it, which you already mentioned: `fs.readFile()`. Once you use that, everything will work as expected.

Comment: If you delete the require cache like this - delete require.cache[require.resolve('file.json')] you shouldn't have the same problem